# Force yarn to install certain modules to given workspace, rather than moving them to shared node_modules of monorepo?

Tags: webpack, babeljs, yarnpkg, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

I have a monorepo (via [yarn workspaces](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/workspaces/)). One of the workspaces is a React app created via [Create React App](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) (I think this is important, because CRA puts Webpack/Babel in its own `node_modules`). Another workspace is a pure JavaScript package with its own set of Webpack + Babel tools.

My problem is that when I'm launching build from the pure JavaScript workspace, I get these:

[image]

However when I separate the workspace into a standalone directory (using copy/paste) and build from there, it builds perfectly fine.

So my guess was there's something wrong with the monorepo itself. I also noticed that specified workspace lacks `@babel`, `babel-runtime` and `regenerator-runtime` in local `node_modules`, so I copy/pasted them from the monorepo's main `node_modules` folder and then the whole thing built fine. Now this is obviously some flaw in the architecture of the yarn monorepo and Webpack + Babel junction.

Is it possible to force `yarn` to install specific modules into the local `node_modules`, rather than "helping me out" by moving them to the shared `node_modules` in the root of monorepo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use **[nohoist](https://yarnpkg.com/blog/2018/02/15/nohoist/)**. This will indicate which modules should be installed locally for the package.

Comment: Not sure why it was downvoted, seems a legit answer. Maybe they expect bit more expanded response, with examples or something. +1 from me however.